# Spring Security form login is not taking to custom user details service when I add a pattern to <http> tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am facing problem while logging in the user using spring security. I'm using spring security 3.1. I want to use a separate authentication manager for the users accessing pattern "/brand/**". so I specified pattern and authentication-manager-ref in "http" tag. I wrote a custom user details service.

Below is my spring-security.xml configuration. If I remove pattern="/brand/**" login form submission is taking to my custom user details service. But when I keep pattern="/brand/**" in "http" tag, it's not working.

```
   <http auto-config="true" pattern="/brand/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="brandAuthenticationManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/brandLogin" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/brand/activity/**" access="hasRole('BRAND_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/brandLogin" authentication-failure-url="/brand/login/failure"
        default-target-url="/" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/brand/denied" />

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/brand/logout/success"
        logout-url="/brand/logout" />
</http>


   <authentication-manager alias="brandAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customBrandUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passEncoder">
            <salt-source user-property="salt" />
        </password-encoder>

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customBrandUserDetailsService" class="com.myproj.service.CustomBrandUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
```

Any ideas on why is it happening like this? Please help ...

Comment: Do you have multiple `<http .. />` tags? If so post your full configuration.

Comment: I have, but I commented the other one. Even then it is not working